# C# how to add parameters to a string with braces at the beginning?

Tags: c#

I have the next string:

```
public const string BaseAddress = "http://test.i-swarm.com/i-swarm/api/v1/";
public const string LoginURL = "{0}sessions";
```

I want to make a url of LoginURL where the {0} is the BaseAddress.
The logical way is not working:

```
string str = string.Format(BaseAddress, LoginURL);
```

It only prints the BaseAddress.
It will work if I do this:

```
string str = string.Format(LoginURL, BaseAddress); //Is this the correct way?
```

Comment: The second one is the logical (as well as the implemented) version. Think about how the call should look like if there are more than one parameter.

Comment: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = string.Format(LoginURL, BaseAddress); //Is this the correct way?
```

Yes, that is the correct way.  Although it doesn't follow the usual pattern people use.  Please read the documentation for the function located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

The first argument is the Format, the second are the arguments/replacement values.  Assuming you want to maintain a constant format, that is usually a hardcoded in the argument as such:

```
string str = string.Format("{0}sessions", BaseAddress);
```

Being as it seems the base address is normally more consistent (but may still be variable) an approach such as the following may be better:

```
public const string BaseAddress = "http://test.i-swarm.com/i-swarm/api/v1/";
public const string LoginURL = "sessions";
string str = string.Format("{0}{1}", BaseAddress, LoginURL);
```

If your end-goal is just URL combination rather than an exercise using `string.Format`, the following may still be a better approach:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://test.i-swarm.com/i-swarm/api/v1/");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "sessions");
```

That way you don't have to worry about whether or not a separator was used in the base address/relative address/etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's not logical way, you are defining parameter in LoginUrl not in BaseAddress, so it's working correctly

If you want it work logicaly do it that way:

```
public const string BaseAddress = "http://test.i-swarm.com/i-swarm/api/v1/{0}";
public const string LoginURL = "sessions";
```

string.Format is replacing `{0}` with first parameter, so it will now work like you want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *logical* way, there's just one way to comply to how `String.Format` works. `String.Format` is defined so that the first parameter contains the string into which parameters will be inserted, then follows a list of the parameters.

If you define the strings like you do, the only correct way is

```
string str = string.Format(LoginURL, BaseAddress);
```

It would be more intuitive, however, if the `BaseAddress` was the format string:

```
public const string BaseAddress = "http://test.i-swarm.com/i-swarm/api/v1/{0}";
public const string LoginURL = "sessions";
```

So you could write

```
string str = String.Format(BaseAddress, LoginURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the correct way is:

```
string str = String.Format(LoginURL, BaseAddress);
```

The format string should always be the first parameter.

Though I feel that:

```
string str = String.Format("{0}sessions", BaseAddress);
```

Is more readable.

Comment: OP mentioned that ;] he's asking why (not my -1)

Comment: Yes. My comment is that you edited your answer so that the downvote is no longer justified. I'd love to undo my downvote, but I can't because it is locked.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I submitted the post before I had completed it. No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use C#'s interpolated strings.

```
string BaseAddress = "http://test.i-swarm.com/i-swarm/api/v1/";
string LoginURL = $"{BaseAddress}sessions";
```

You can have multiple parameters. This is a safer method of formatting strings as when using string.Format you need to make sure that order of parameters are correct. With this new way you don't have to.

```
string foo = "foo";
int bar = 4;
string result = $"{bar} hello {foo}";
```

Reference:

- [What's with the dollar sign ($"string")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878549/whats-with-the-dollar-sign-string)
- [MSDN - Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)